# Convert a bytes object with hexadecimal characters to string?

Tags: python, encoding, decode

I'm having way more trouble with this than I'd like to admit. I've checked numerous posts already with no luck. I'm trying to convert a byte object like this:

```
b = b'%PDF-1.5\r%\xe2\xe3\xcf\xd3\r\n'
```

into a string variable.

I have tried the following already,

```
import codecs
codecs.decode(b, 'hex')
# Error: decoding with 'hex' codec failed (Error: Non-hexadecimal digit found)

b.decode('hex')
# LookupError: 'hex' is not a text encoding; use codecs.decode() to handle arbitrary codecs


b.unhexlify(_)
#AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'unhexlify'


str(b)
# just gives me the same bytes object with str type


b.decode('utf-8')
# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 10: invalid continuation byte
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: What is the string supposed to look like for this example? You are obviously reading PDF documents, do you want to extract information from them?

Answer (score 1):

What you have there is a PDF file; while partially ASCII-text based, PDF files are not plain text. You can find a way to decode even the magic bytes in the header (iso8859-1 should do), but as soon as you hit a deflate-compressed stream you'll have sequences of full-entropy 256 bytes, that cannot be decoded meaningfully with any codec.

IOW: there's no way to meaningfully decode the whole byte content of a PDF file to a Unicode string, as it's not a straight representation of Unicode codepoints of any kind. It's like trying to decode a JPEG file to a Unicode string: it makes no sense *and* it is not possible.

If you want to extract text from a PDF file you have to actually parse and decode its structure, which is not trivial at all.

Answer (score 0):

Actually `b` already is a string. You can know it by type checking and verifying that it prints all your special characters:

```
>>> b = b'%PDF-1.5\r%\xe2\xe3\xcf\xd3\r\n'
>>> type(b)
<type 'str'>
>>> print(b)
%ÔŃ¤Ë1.5

>>>
```

If you have real bytes object you convert from bytes to string using `.decode(encoding)`. Bad thing is that you need to know your encoding to do this.

I went trial-and-error with couple of encodings from this site: https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/standard-encodings.html. It didn't produce the errors with iso8859_15, but I cannot guarantee it's a good one. Here is a snippet:

```
line.decode('iso8859_15')
```

Comment: Hey @jedzej I added the source of where I'm getting the byte variable from above. When I print it without any formatting it still prints as your first line and its type is still bytes.

Comment: No luck with the `iso8859_15` encoding. I'll give the rest a shot too.

Comment: https://repl.it/repls/HoneydewRosybrownMotion check this snippet, it somehow decoded the data, but anyway if you're dealing with binary-headered files like PDF it may be indecodable at all, since the structure of the header may not fit into any kind of encoding; it makes more sense to parse binary data and extract and decode only the parts you're sure about they come with certain decoding instead of blind-decoding the whole file

Comment: Beware, you only get `type(b)` as `str` on Python 2.x. A Python 3.x version would give `class bytes`. Python 3 `str` is Python 2 `unicode`